# React - Socket listener not working in child component

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-context

In my react application, I have a global context which initially creates a socket connection whenn the app starts, and provides it to the rest of the application.

**SocketContext**:

```
import { createContext } from "react"
import io from "socket.io-client"

// Connect to socket server
export const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000")
export const SocketContext = createContext()
```

This Context is provided to the entire application:

**App.js**

```
       import { SocketContext, socket } from "./SocketContext"

        // Provides socket to the entire application
        <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path="/signup"
                    exact
                    element={<Signup />}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    element={
                        <ProtectedRoute>
                            <Home />
                        </ProtectedRoute>
                    }
                />
 
            </Routes>
        </SocketContext.Provider>
```

I listen to socket events inside `Signup.js` without any problem, however when attempting to do the same inside `Home` component, no event listeners are fired.

The Socket code (This works inside Signup component (not a protected route), but not Home component):

```
const socket = useContext(SocketContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("connect", () => {
            console.log("Client connected")
        })
    }, [socket])
```

The home component is wrapped inside `ProtectedRoute` component to ensure that users are authenticated. The code shown above also works in `ProtectedRoute`. But will not work in `Home.js` which is a child of `ProtectedRoute`.

**ProtectedRoute:**

```
const isAuth = "value"

// E.g return Home component
if (isAuth) return children
else return <Login />
```

I would not like to move the `socket.on` listeners into `ProtectedRoute`, so how can I allow the listeners to work inside the child (Home component). Any ideas on why the socket listener will not work in `Home`, however will work in `Signup (not a protected route)`, as well as the `ProtectedRoute` component? Thanks.